# Entity Framework return non null when no row should exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following query. I want the var to be `null` if the row does not exist but it always has a value. What am I doing wrong.

```
var results = dbContext.Users.Where(m => UserName == userName && Password == password).First();

if (results !=null)
     return true;
```

Comment: var results = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => UserName == userName && Password == password);

Comment: It seems most responders are missing the point of your question. The `First()` method will throw an exception if there are no rows that match the condition. If you're getting a non-null value in `results` (which should probably be singular as you're only asking for one) then there must be a row that satisfies your condition. Could you have multiple rows with the same `UserName` and `Password` in your database?

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised you are seeing a value if you expect the result of the Where to not return any results as First() would throw an exception on an empty collection. You could remove the Where method all together and put the predicate within the FirstOrDefault to make it cleaner like below:

```
var results = dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => UserName == userName && Password == password);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your code like this:

```
var results = dbContext.Users.Where(m => m.UserName == userName && m.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Explanation**
Since the diff might not be visible at the glance look, the problem with the query is that "m" is not used at all so as long as there is at least one user the results variable won't be null. That is also reason why the .First() is not throwing an exception when there is no match. This obviously expects that there are variables UserName and userName with same values (and same goes for password) but I don't think there is another possible explanation which would be buildable.

Comment: I think, you should move condition into `FirstOrDefault` method.

Comment: Although it would be my peferred way to do the query, I don't think that it affects results not being null in any way

Comment: It's don't affects to result. Just I think tnat variant "get first element for this condition" more readable then "get elements for this condition then get first element". Anyway it's write answer.

Comment: While I agree with better readability I don't think it's right answer since changing .First() to .FirstOrDefault() would affect result not being null if there shouldn't be any match in the DB.

Comment: That did it putting the m in and using FirstOrDefault. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) function is the one you're looking for. If there is one or more result, it will return that one. If there are no results, it will return the default value (which, in the case of your `User` object, is null)

```
var results = dbContext.Users.Where(m => UserName == userName && Password == password)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FirstOrDefault()` that will return `null` if the row does not exist.

```
  var results = dbContext.Users.Where(m => m.UserName == userName && m.Password == password)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (results !=null)
         return true;
```